# How to avoid null values when generating insert statement

Tags: postgresql

I´m trying to create an insert statement with my database values, to send to my app.

But I don´t know how to avoid values if they are `NULL`, and if `NULL` I want to put an empty string, like `''`.

My statement is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW atendimentopublico.vw_insert_atendimento_motivo_encerramento AS 

SELECT TRANSLATE ('INSERT INTO AtendimentoMotivoEncerramento (Id, Descricao) VALUES' ||  array((SELECT '(''' || ame.amen_id || ''',''' || ame.amen_dsmotivoencerramento || ''')' 
FROM atendimentopublico.atendimento_motivo_encerramento ame 
WHERE ame.amen_icuso = 1 
ORDER BY ame.amen_id))::text,'"{}','');

ALTER TABLE atendimentopublico.vw_insert_atendimento_motivo_encerramento OWNER TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE atendimentopublico.vw_insert_atendimento_motivo_encerramento TO postgres;
```

Comment: Replace `fieldname` which may be NULL with `COALESCE(fieldname, '')`.

Comment: @Akina I got erro with integer values for example, can´t run my query

Comment: @DiegoMacario, all arguments for COALESCE must be of the same type. If your first arg is of type int, you need to use an int as the second argument

Comment: *I got erro with integer values* Either convert field to string or use zero instead of empty string.